# Como eu faço um select para retornar o nome do vendedor com maior salário

Tags: sql, select

```
CREATE TABLE vendedor (
  matricula VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
  nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  endereço VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  telefone_vend VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  salario DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  cpf_vendedor VARCHAR(11)
);
```

Quero fazer um select desse jeito mas que também retorne o nome:

```
SELECT max(salario) FROM vendedor
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Basta você adicionar a coluna desejada como retorno da consulta:

```
SELECT max(salario), nome 
FROM vendedor
GROUP BY nome
```

---

Precisando apenas do maior salário, é possível limitar a quantidade retornada através do [`TOP`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp):

```
SELECT TOP 1 max(salario), nome 
FROM vendedor
GROUP BY nome
```

Comment: Ele deu esse erro: Query Error: Error: ER_MIX_OF_GROUP_FUNC_AND_FIELDS: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'test.vendedor.nome'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (obs: tô usando o db fiddle)

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!

Answer (score -3):

Select MAX(salario),nome
From vendedor
Group by nome